# Are there any corrections one might suggest to this table of different Hebrew pronounciations?

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, ashkenazi

| Sound | Modern Israeli (Based on Sephardic pronounciation) | Ashkenazi Chabad (inc. other non-Oberland / Unterland Chassidim. | Ashkenazi Chassidic (Oberlander, Unterlander and Galitzer, e.g. Satmar) | Ashkenazi Litvish | Ashkenazi Yekkish | Yemenite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| אָ | A | O, E.g. יִשְׂרָאֵל Yisroel | Open: OO E.g. עָמַד Oomad Closed: O E.g. עָמְדָה Omdoo | O | O | O |
| אַ | A | A | A | A | A | A |
| אֲ | A | A | A | A | A | A |
| בֵ | EH | EY (as in may) E.g. אַחֵינוּ Acheynoo . Sometimes EH | AY (sounds like eye) E.g. אַחֵינוּ Achaynee |  |  |  |
| אֶ | EH | EY Open: EY E.g. חֶסֶד Cheysed Closed: EH E.g. Ibid. | EY E.g. חֶסֶד Cheysed Closed: EH E.g. Ibid. | E | A (at end?) |  |
| בְּ | “Stop sign” / EH | “Stop sign” /EE? | “Stop sign” /EE |  |  |  |
| אֱ | EH | EY | EH | ? | E | E |
| אִ | EE | EE | EE | EE | EE | EE |
| אֹ | O | OY As in boy | OY E.g. Oylom If last syllable and emphasis on first: EH E.g. סוכות sikkes | EY, as in may Eylom If last syllable,Ibid.: E.g. סוכות sukkes | OW As in no E.g. Owlom | OU As in Bonjour |
| וּ | OO (like food) E.g. ברוכים broochim | OO | Open: EE (like seek) Closed: i (like sit) E.g. Avoyseynee, brichim | OO Avoysaynoo | OO Avowsaynoo | OO |
| אֻ | OO (like food) | OO | Open: EE (like seek) Closed: i (like sit) | OO | OO | OO |
| ת | T | S | S | S | S | TH |

I would greatly appreciate any additions or corrections. I have not managed to include examples for everything yet. I am also no expert on this by any means.

By "open" and "closed", I refer to whether there is an open or closed syllable. In other words, whether the syllable ends with a vowel sound (open) or a consonant (closed).

If I have omitted anything, it is not to diminish the importance of any community, but rather a result of my ignorance!

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Based on my experience, segol is always "eh" and never "ey". I have heard people pronounce the first segol in a string of two segolim as "ey" but not in Chabad. (Ex. "cheysed", "zeycher", "meylech".) Cholam is either "oy" or it is "ey". Sheva is blended in to the next consonant or it is "ih". Be sure to include that chataf-patach with ayin is "ai" as in "maiseh", "tainis", "mairiv", etc.

Comment: @ezra What about “peysach”?

Comment: @ezra, I think you are right. In this clip of the Rebbe, he pronounces ארץ as Eretz, not Eyretz. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il77SOQUlEU&t=54s

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you use [the International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (or something similar, like [ASCII-IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirshenbaum)) rather than relying on people's knowing what you mean by "EH", "A", "OO (like food)", etc.

Comment: @N.T. the question is specifically asking for corrections. This is a direct answer, advising how to correct the table.